# proper coding with array.push

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, push

I've found some code on a site and been tinkering with it a little.   It involves some functions to add and delete students (the add code is below) from an array - into a value field.  I can't figure out why in tarnations we need this extra piece of code, however.

Here is the js code:

```
var students  = ['Paulie', 'Nicole', 'Kevin', 'Mare'];
function addClick(){
    var addRemove   = document.getElementById('addRemoveStudent');
    var studentsBox = document.getElementById('studentsBox')
    students.push(addRemove.value);
    addRemove.value = '';
    studentsBox.value = students.join(', ');
}
```

My question is: Why do we need the `addRemove.value = '';` line?  I've tested it without that code and it still works fine.  Is there a reason we need that?

I can send more code including the HTML but didn't what to overwhelm anyone with the volume.

Thanks so much in advance!
-Anthony

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary. I guess semantically it means to clear the `addRemove` box first before replacing the value.

Answer (score 2):

It's optional, but it's simply to clear the text box so the user can enter a brand new value if they want to run the function again.

Answer (score 2):

To clear the value of the `addRemoveStudent` ( I think it is a `input type="text"`) Just for it, It is not needed in the array. Just to clear the value of that control.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably `addRemove` is an `input` element. Setting the `value` property of an `input` element to an empty string `''` means that the input is emptied: it will have no text in it.

My guess is that this function is run when a button is clicked, so it adds a new student to the array, updates the `studentsBox` field with the right data, and clears the input element so you can add more if the user wishes to do so.